# Saving a file in a text delimiter format in Micropython

Tags: python, micropython

I want to record date and temperature in a text delimiter style but using the least possible consumption (i.e. without using any libraries such as CSV or Pandas).

I have tried this so far:

```
while hours < 2:
    hours += 1
    text = "%4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d" % utime.localtime()[:6], get_temp()
    row.append(text)
    utime.sleep(1)
```

That inputs this:

```
[('2021-05-08 16:05:44', 347), ('2021-05-08 16:05:45', 344)]
```

However, I would like the data to store in this kind of format:

```
"2021-05-08 16:05:44", 22
"2021-05-08 16:05:45", 19
...
```

Comment: could you please paste the whole snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
text = "%4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d" % utime.localtime()[:6], get_temp()
```

You are setting the variable `text` to a *tuple* (a `(x, y)` value), not a string. If you wanted to output rows in the format you've shown, you might do something like:

```
with open('output.txt', 'a') as fd:
  fd.write('"%s", %d\n' % text)
```

For example, the following code:

```
import time as utime
import random


def get_temp():
    return random.randint(100, 400)


hours = 0
row = []

while hours < 2:
    hours += 1
    text = "%4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d" % utime.localtime()[:6], get_temp()
    row.append(text)
    utime.sleep(1)

with open('data.txt', 'a') as fd:
    for val in row:
        fd.write('"%s", %d\n' % val)
```

Will result in the file `data.txt` containing something like the following data:

```
"2021-05-08 11:50:51", 319
"2021-05-08 11:50:52", 221
```

Comment: This work like a champ. Exactly what I was looking for. One question, do you know how could I get to have a first row to use as a header? I.e., Date, Temp

Comment: I mean...just print out a header row before you start printing out your data (e.g., before the `for val in row` loop).